# Netbeans 7 debugger doesn't break where it should, breaks where it shouldn't

Tags: gwt, netbeans, netbeans-7

**1) Breaking where it shouldn't:** In tools > options > misc > java debugger > step filters, I have "Do not step into" set to synthetic methods (checked), static initializers (checked), and added entries for classes matching java.*, java.util.AbstractExecutorService, and java.util.ThreadPoolExecutor (redundancy in the pursuit of overkill).

Despite this, the debugger always breaks at  **java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()**. I have tried this both with "Step through the filters to reach unfiltered code" checked and cleared.

**2) Not breaking where it should:** In a GWT MVP project, I have set breakpoints in a Presenter, and they no longer trip (used to). Server RPC breakpoints trip just fine, and I don't see any changes that would cause changes in the way client side code is treated. FWIW, I have the gwt4nb plugin installed & activated.

Any ideas on where to look for the problems behind these behaviors?

---

*Update*: It seems that NetBeans really doesn't like using GWT version 2.2. With the following in the pom...

```
<gwt.maven.plugin.version>2.2.0</gwt.maven.plugin.version>
<gwt.version>2.2.0</gwt.version>
```

...the Project -> Properties -> Frameworks doesn't even show GWT. If I manually add GWT, it adds the following nodes to the project properties (oddly, it does not replace the existing GWT version node):

```
<gwt.version>2.0.3</gwt.version>
<runTarget>welcomeGWT.html</runTarget>
```

The project properties dialog doesn't offer any configuration options for the GWT framework. I still haven't found a way to get 2.2.0 to stick, and I think this is contributing to the client-side debugging problem.

Answer (score 1):

The typical problem is that the code being stepped through (compiled) code does not match the source code in the project. If I update some source code and save it, and then step through a deployed project in the debugger, I can produce the same behavior.